# Error: Program type already present Android Studio

Tags: java, android, api, twitter

estoy intentando usar la API de `Twitter` para solamente mostrar un tweet, la aplicación no tiene nada de código pero me da el siguiente error:

> Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21$1
>   Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21$1, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

He estado leyendo por internet que el problema es que tengo algo duplicado en el build.grandle pero he revisado y no veo nada raro, este es mi codigo:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Result;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterException;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.models.Tweet;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetui.TweetUtils;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetui.TweetView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final LinearLayout myLayout
            = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layTwitter);

    final long tweetId = 510908133917487104L;
    TweetUtils.loadTweet(tweetId, new Callback<Tweet>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<Tweet> result) {
            myLayout.addView(new TweetView(MainActivity.this, result.data));
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
            // Toast.makeText(...).show();
        }
    });

}
}
```

Y este el código del `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.cpadilla.embedtweet"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner        "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    }
}

dependencies {
implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.1.1'
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

La única linea que he añadido yo es la de

> implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.1.1'

Muchas gracias por adelantado, ¿alguien sabe como arreglar este problema?

Un saludo!

Answer (score 2):

Ya he encontrado una solución, no se si será buena pero funcionar funciona, lo he declarado de la siguiente manera:

```
compile ('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.1.1'){
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```

Y con esto funciona perfectamente

Comment: El mensaje que comentas en tu pregunta no lo había visto pero indica "Program type already present:" en realidad habla de una clase duplicada por lo que yo creo que esta sería la respuesta correcta.